Error when insert data with javascript form
I have an order creation form that allows me to enter information for several products to be linked to the order.
Each product can have production items, and I'd like to add the possibility of entering the number of products to be produced for each task.
The product and job parts of the form are dynamically generated by javascript.
The current problem is that my php file doesn't handle the input corresponding to the quantity of products for the production tasks.
if i create an order with only 1 product, it correctly processes its production tasks and the quantity of each.
If I create an order with several products, the first one will be processed correctly, but for the subsequent products, the quantity of each task will not be retrieved and inserted.
Javascript product production posts form :
  function addProductField() {
    var productFields = document.getElementById("product_fields");
    var index = productFields.childElementCount + 1;

    fetch("production_posts.php").then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      var productionPostsOptions = data.map(post => `
          <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="production_post_id_${index}[]" value="${post.id}" id="production_post_${post.id}_${index}">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="production_post_${post.id}_${index}">
                  ${post.name}
              </label>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="production_post_quantity_${post.id}_${index}">
                  Quantité totale pour ${post.name} du produit_${index}
                  production_post_quantity_${post.id}_${index}
                  production_post_quantity_${index}[]
              </label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="production_post_quantity_${index}[]" id="production_post_quantity_${post.id}_${index}" placeholder="Quantité totale">
          </div>
      `).join("");
.....

php code for inserting products and their production tasks :
// Insérer les détails de produits dans la table order_product_details
    $product_count = count($_POST['product_name_']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $product_count; $i++) {
        $product_name = $_POST['product_name_'][$i];
        $product_ref = $_POST['product_ref_'][$i];
        $product_attributes = $_POST['product_attributes_'][$i];
        $product_comment = $_POST['product_comment_'][$i];
        $product_rush = isset($_POST['product_rush_'][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
        $product_template = isset($_POST['product_template_'][$i]) ? 1 : 0;
        $product_production_days = (int)$_POST['product_production_days_'][$i];
        $product_production_days_rush = (int)$_POST['product_production_days_rush_'][$i];

        $product_custom_file_comment = $_POST['product_custom_file_comment_'][$i] ?? '';


        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, product_ref, product_attributes, rush_option, template_option, production_day, production_day_rush, comment, product_state) 
        VALUES (:product_name, :product_ref, :product_attributes, :rush_option, :template_option, :production_day, :production_day_rush, :product_comment, 7)");
        $stmt->execute([
            ':product_name' => $product_name,
            ':product_ref' => $product_ref,
            ':product_attributes' => $product_attributes,
            ':product_comment' => $product_comment,
            ':rush_option' => $product_rush,
            ':template_option' => $product_template,
            ':production_day' => $product_production_days,
            ':production_day_rush' => $product_production_days_rush
        ]);
        $product_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO order_products (order_id, product_id) VALUES (:order_id, :product_id)");
        $stmt->execute([
            ':order_id' => $order_id,
            ':product_id' => $product_id
        ]);

        $production_post_ids = $_POST['production_post_id_' . ($i + 1)] ?? [];
        $production_post_quantities = $_POST['production_post_quantity_' . ($i + 1)] ?? [];
    
        // Insérer les relations entre les produits et les étapes de production avec les quantités
        foreach ($production_post_ids as $index => $post_id) {
            $quantity = isset($production_post_quantities[$index]) ? (int)$production_post_quantities[$index] : 0;
    
            // Vérifier que les données sont valides
            if ($post_id && $quantity > 0) {
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO product_production (product_id, production_post_id, production_post_state_id, total_quantity) 
                    VALUES (:product_id, :production_post_id, 1, :total_quantity)
                ");
                $stmt->execute([
                    ':product_id' => $product_id,
                    ':production_post_id' => $post_id,
                    ':total_quantity' => $quantity
                ]);
            }
        }
...

don't hesitate to let me know if you're missing any information or if there's a problem with my code.
I tried changing the data insertion method and the form layout.
For each product, each production task must be inserted with the associated quantity entered in the total_quantity field of the product_production table.
Currently, if there are several products, this only works for the first product.

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a database problem?

I don't get your form field naming scheme there. Why, for example, is the quantity field named production_post_quantity_${index}[] - containing an actual index in the field name itself, and have it create an array of the submitted values at the same time? You don't need to input more than one quantity per product, do you?

Your looping in PHP depends on the number of items in the $_POST['product_name_'] array. But we can't see anything in the HTML which relates to that, and so we can't see how many entries would be in that array, or why. So your question is not really answerable as it stands. Please [edit] your post to provide a [mre] of your issue so we can help you properly. See also [ask], for reference and useful guidance. Thanks.

@NicoHaase for me it's a php problem but maybe i'm wrong.

@C3roe I do need several quantities.
1 quantity must be associated with a production post for each product.
Not all production stations have the same quantity of products to process.
Example for the first product in my order: in my production stations I have DTF, which needs to produce 25 products, but for the other station, called Flocking, I need to have a quantity of 10.

Why did you write $production_post_ids = $_POST['production_post_id_' . ($i + 1)] instead of $production_post_ids = $_POST['production_post_id_' . $i]? I can't work out your logic there. It seems like you're jumping ahead to the next index, but it's unclear why.

Don't put $index in the input name. It should just be name="production_post_quantity_[]"
